# Image reloads in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am rendering mathematical equations with a view latextimageview which is subclass of UIImageView inside UITableView.

But problem I'm facing is that image view reloads every time i scroll.
how to stop this loading?

Comment: could you explain more about the `latextimageview`?

Comment: I think https://github.com/TeamSlader/iOSLaTeX/blob/master/iOSLaTeX/Classes/LaTeXImageView.swift is meant

Comment: Please show more code, expecially `cellForRowAt:`. When does the view render itself? Do you call it, or is it done by some internal magic?

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView dynamically creates the cells as they are shown on the screen to save performance.

Every time a cell is loaded, `cellForRowAt:` is being called.

So make sure that you don't do your heavy calculations in `cellForRowAt:` - make them somewhere before showing the table view or cache the images you calculated in an array or dictionary for example.